# how can I toggle a div individually when outputting from a php while loop

Tags: php, jquery, forms, while-loop, toggle

I have this php script -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$id' ORDER BY com_id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $date = $row['date'];
    $mydate = date("M jS g:i a",strtotime($date));
    $user = $row['user'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $reply = $row['reply'];
    $comID = $row['com_id'];

    echo '<div id="comuser">'.$user.': </div>';
    echo '<div id="icomment">'.$comment.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="comdate">'.$mydate.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="replyBTN">reply</div>';

        echo '<form method="post" id="replyForm" action="get_reply.php?reply='.$comID.'">';
        echo '<input type="text" id="addReply" name="addReply" placeholder="add reply">';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="subCom" value="submit">';
        echo '</form>';


}
} else {
    echo "<div id='noCom'>no comments..</div>";
}
```

I want to echo the div 'replyBTN' and use jquery to toggle the form, here is my jquery click function -

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#replyBTN").click(function(){
        $("#replyForm").toggle();
    });
});
```

It currently will only toggle the first reply button in the first comment, all other reply buttons will not work in the other comments. Why does the jquery only toogle the first reply button?

Comment: The reason it only works for the first one, is because **ID's are unique**, so jQuery stops searching for more elements once the first one is found, simply because there can't be more elements with the same ID, it's invalid.

Comment: ...therefore, use a class.

Comment: So will changing to a class fix this?

Comment: Ahh haa thanks! If you want, post as an answer and ill accept it

Comment: @RyanD I posted a community wiki answer and you're welcome. I can't take all the credit for this. Adeneo did put in the comment first and I was about to enter something similar. The question can be marked as solved.

Comment: Great will do thanks! Need to wait 8 minutes..

Comment: @Fred-ii- I updated the question to see how I can only toggle the individual form and not all at once..

Comment: @RyanD That would should have been another question really. I'll delete what I posted below then.

Comment: No thats cool I will post as another question and accept your answer

Comment: @RyanD I revisited the question to check on its current status. I noticed you rolled back to your original post. I undeleted my answer. You should have pinged me directly ;-)

Comment: Yep perfect thanks @Fred -ii-

Comment: @RyanD You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is fit as a community wiki; I've nothing to gain from this, nor do I expect rep gain for it.

Taken from comments:

> *The reason it only works for the first one, is because **ID's are unique**, so jQuery stops searching for more elements once the first one is found, simply because there can't be more elements with the same ID, it's invalid. – adeneo*

and mine

> *...therefore, use a class – Fred -ii-*